# Eclipse: Plug-In Development wizard missing when creating a new project

Tags: java, eclipse, plugins, project, wizard

I would like to create a Plug-In project in Eclipse (the needed Plug-Ins are installed), but when creating a new project (File --> New --> Other) the option is missing.

[this is my screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/JyXTu.png)

[this is how it shuold look](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aWNtA.png)

Can anybody help?

Comment: That looks like you don't actually have the plug-in development plug-ins installed. Look in the 'Plug-Ins' list in the Eclipse > About > installation Details dialog and check for various `org.eclipse.pde.xxxx` plug-ins.

Comment: Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers (https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2022-12/r/eclipse-ide-enterprise-java-and-web-developers) . use this version.

Comment: ＠greg-449, Eclipse IDE for Enterprise Java and Web Developers (https://www.eclipse.org/downloads/packages/release/2022-12/r/eclipse-ide-enterprise-java-and-web-developers),  This package includes: 1. Data Tools Platform , 
2. Git integration for Eclipse , 3. Eclipse Java Development Tools , 4. Eclipse Java EE Developer Tools, 5. Maven Integration for Eclipse , `6.Eclipse Plug-in Development Environment` , Please check it again.